# Sed remove matching lines script

Tags: sed, bsd

I'm requesting help with a very simple script...

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f

sed '/11,yahoo/d'
sed '/2506,stackover flow/d'
sed '/2536,reddit/d'
```

Just need it to remove three matches that account for 18408 in my file, data.csv

```
% sed -f remove.sed < data.csv 
sed: 3: remove.sed: unterminated substitute pattern
```

Doing these same lines individually is no problem at all, so what am I doing wrong with this?

Using freeBSD 10.1 and its implementation of sed, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, being a sed script, should not have "sed" at each line.

Either change it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f

/11,yahoo/d
/2506,stackover flow/d
/2536,reddit/d
```

Or to

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -e /11,yahoo/d \
-e /2506,stackover flow/d \
-e /2536,reddit/d
```

Comment: Thanks, rslemos! I should have spotted my obvious mistake myself. Thanks for the extra eyes.

Comment: With the sed script, I'm trying to print matching lines:
`#!/usr/bin/sed -f
/reddit/p`

but that prints entire file adding a -n in front of the / results in an error. Any ideas?

Comment: You can only have a  single option cluster on the shebang line. Try `#!/usr/bin/sed -nf` (newline) `/reddit/p` or just `grep reddit file`.