# Removing duplicate line with only a column that is different

Tags: shell, awk, duplicates

I have a file as follows:

```
ENSG00000087266:I10_35  chr4:2815905-2816105    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I10_35  chr4:2815905-2816105    +   I   U
ENSG00000087266:I10_36  chr4:2815955-2816155    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I10_36  chr4:2815955-2816155    +   I   U
ENSG00000087266:I16_18  chr4:2826151-2826351    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_27   chr4:2797290-2797490    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_28   chr4:2797340-2797540    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_28   chr4:2797340-2797540    +   I   U
ENSG00000087266:I3_29   chr4:2797390-2797590    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_30   chr4:2797440-2797640    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_30   chr4:2797440-2797640    +   I   U
ENSG00000087266:I3_31   chr4:2797490-2797690    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_38   chr4:2797840-2798040    +   I   B
ENSG00000000003:E1_1    chrX:99894942-99895142  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_10   chrX:99891638-99891838  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_11   chrX:99891688-99891888  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_12   chrX:99891738-99891938  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_13   chrX:99891788-99891988  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_14   chrX:99891838-99892038  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_15   chrX:99891888-99892088  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_16   chrX:99891938-99892138  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_1    chrX:99891188-99891388  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_2    chrX:99891238-99891438  -   E   U
```

I would like to remove all the duplicate columns that have "U" in their 5 th column such that the file is

```
ENSG00000087266:I10_35  chr4:2815905-2816105    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I10_36  chr4:2815955-2816155    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I16_18  chr4:2826151-2826351    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_27   chr4:2797290-2797490    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_28   chr4:2797340-2797540    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_29   chr4:2797390-2797590    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_30   chr4:2797440-2797640    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_31   chr4:2797490-2797690    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_38   chr4:2797840-2798040    +   I   B
ENSG00000000003:E1_1    chrX:99894942-99895142  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_10   chrX:99891638-99891838  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_11   chrX:99891688-99891888  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_12   chrX:99891738-99891938  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_13   chrX:99891788-99891988  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_14   chrX:99891838-99892038  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_15   chrX:99891888-99892088  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_16   chrX:99891938-99892138  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_1    chrX:99891188-99891388  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_2    chrX:99891238-99891438  -   E   U
```

In short if the lines are duplicate for all the columns except the last one, keep the line that ends in 'B' and remove the duplicate that ends with 'U'

So far I have tried using

```
  while read id; do  sed -i '/"$id"/{/U/d}' file_that_contains_duplicates.txt; done < list_of_duplicate_ids.txt
```

which didn't output anything; 
 currently I am running

```
 while read id; do  awk -v id=$id '$1!=id && $5!="U"' file_that_contains_duplicates.txt; done < list_of_duplicate_ids.txt | sort -u which somehow works but outputs repeated lines and also takes some time.
```

Comment: `sed '/U$/d' filename`, if you like sed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed remove matching lines script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022558/sed-remove-matching-lines-script)

Comment: @EdMorton: I just added some more lines to make my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '!(seen[$1,$2,$3,$4]++ && ($5 == "U"))' file
ENSG00000087266:I10_35  chr4:2815905-2816105    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I10_36  chr4:2815955-2816155    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I16_18  chr4:2826151-2826351    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_27   chr4:2797290-2797490    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_28   chr4:2797340-2797540    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_29   chr4:2797390-2797590    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_30   chr4:2797440-2797640    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_31   chr4:2797490-2797690    +   I   B
ENSG00000087266:I3_38   chr4:2797840-2798040    +   I   B
ENSG00000000003:E1_1    chrX:99894942-99895142  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_10   chrX:99891638-99891838  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_11   chrX:99891688-99891888  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_12   chrX:99891738-99891938  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_13   chrX:99891788-99891988  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_14   chrX:99891838-99892038  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_15   chrX:99891888-99892088  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_16   chrX:99891938-99892138  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_1    chrX:99891188-99891388  -   E   U
ENSG00000000003:E2_2    chrX:99891238-99891438  -   E   U
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "duplicate" in this case, since you're simply removing all lines which end with "D". That's [easily done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763324/removing-duplicate-line-with-only-a-column-that-is-different#comment86542381_49763324):

```
sed '/U$/d'
```

(match lines ending with "U", then **d**elete.)

If you want only lines that end with "B":

```
sed -n '/B$/p'
```

(match lines ending with "B", then **p**rint.)

Comment: if you see the lines with id ENSG00000087266:I3_28  everything except the last column is the same , I want to retain the one that contains 'B' in the last column.